# How to get MAX values in JOINs in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I have 4 tables that I need to join to pull data from:

```
| Account Table: A  | Plate Table: P | TollTransaction  : T | FinTrans Table: F |
=================================================================================
| AccountId         | AccountId      | AccountId            | AcctId            |
| AccountNumber     | LicPlateNo     | LicPlateNo           | FinTransTypeCode  |
| CurrentBalance    | EndDate        | EntryTransDt         | BusinessDay       |
| ActualTagDeposit  |                |                      |                   |
=================================================================================
```

The relationships:

```
A.AccountId = P.AccountId = F.AcctId  != T.AccountId  <--(NOT EQUAL)
P.LicPlateNo = T.LicPlateNo
```

I want to show:

```
A.AccountNumber  
A.CurrentBalance  
Max(BusinessDay)  -->(Last Payment Date)  
Max(EntryTransDt)      -->(Last Transaction Date)  
ActualTagDeposit

WHERE P.EndDate IS NULL  
  AND A.CurrentBalance > 0  
  AND F.FinTransTypeCode = 'pymt'  
  AND Max(EntryTransDt) <= '2017-07-28'  
  AND A.ActualTagDeposit >= 10
```

My attempt at the code so far:

```
SELECT A.AccountNumber
      ,A.CurrentBalance
      ,MAX(F.Last_Pymt_date) AS Last_Pymnt_Date
      ,MAX(T.Last_Transaction) AS LastTransaction
      ,A.ActualTagDeposit

FROM 

    ( SELECT AccountId 
            ,LicPlateNo
            ,MAX(EntryTransDt) AS Last_Transaction
      FROM TollTransaction
      GROUP BY AccountId, LicPlateNo
     ) T
INNER JOIN Plate P ON T.LicPlateNo = P.LicPlateNo
INNER JOIN Account A ON P.AccountId = A.AccountId
LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT AcctId
            ,FinTransTypeCode
            ,MAX(BusinessDay) AS Last_Pymt_Date
      FROM FinTransMaster
      GROUP BY AcctID, FinTransTypeCode
     ) F ON A.AccountId = F.AcctId

WHERE P.EndDate is null
  AND A.CurrentBalance > 0
  AND F.FinTransTypeCode = 'pymt'
  AND Last_Transaction <= '2017-07-28'
  AND A.ActualTagDeposit >= 10

GROUP BY AccountNumber, CurrentBalance, Last_Pymt_date, Last_Transaction, A.ActualTagDeposit

ORDER BY AccountNumber
```

But I get duplicates with this code. Obviously, the `MAX` part in my code is not working somehow?

A sample of the results I get:

```
AccountNumber   CurrentBalance  Last_Pymnt_Date LastTransaction ActualTagDeposit
21233815        12.34       2016-12-12       2016-08-15     10.00
21233815        12.34       2016-12-12       2017-03-11     10.00
21234567       123.12       2017-06-20       2016-12-25     10.00
21234568         1.23       2017-06-05       2012-07-12     10.00
21234568         1.23       2017-06-05       2012-07-21     10.00
```

Comment: Remove `LAST_Pymnt_Date` and `Last_Transaction` from your `GROUP BY`

Comment: Okay, so you have identified that the max(last transaction) isn't working.  That will point you to that table.  You're not grouping by something else coming from that table.

My guess:  Might you have accounts with multiple license plates?

Comment: YES. I do have Accounts with multiple License plates. But I only just want the Last crossing irrespective of which license plate crossed.

Comment: I removed the LAST_Pymnt_Date and Last_Transaction grouping and I'm not getting any duplicates. But I wonder if I am getting an accurate number of results.

Comment: You should be.  Basically you can either group by those columns (keep all unique rows) or `MAX()` those columns (keep only max row).  If you do both, the group by supersedes the `MAX()`, and you end up with multiple dates like you are getting.

Comment: I removed the  AND F.FinTransTypeCode = 'pymt'  and instead inserted that in the select generated table  by adding code : WHERE FinTransTypeCode = 'pymt' ___ This gave me a couple thousand more records.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because one account can have multiple license plates.  If you added P.LicPlateNo to your current select, you would see something like this:

```
AccountNumber  CurrentBalance  Last_Pymnt_Date LastTransaction ActualTagDeposit LicPlateNo
21233815            12.34       2016-12-12       2016-08-15        10.00         A123
21233815            12.34       2016-12-12       2017-03-11        10.00         B456
```

I would like to say just remove `Plates` all together, but it seems like you have to use it as the link to table `T`, so the next best move is to do a `MAX()` in your outer query (as you are doing).  The problem is that you also have the maxed columns in your outer `GROUP BY`, which prevents them from being aggregated in your `MAX()`

Changing your outer group by will solve the problem:

```
GROUP BY AccountNumber, CurrentBalance, A.ActualTagDeposit
```